# Is there a way to have a dictionary as an entry of a pandas Dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Something like:

```
d={'a':1, 'b'=2}
data=pandas.DataFrame()
data['new column'] = d
data['new column'][0]
```

where the last command will return the dictionary d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the dictionary in a list, so that the dictionary will be treated as an element instead of an iterable:

```
d={'a':1, 'b': 2}
data=pd.DataFrame()
data['new column'] = [d]
data['new column'][0]

# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: this will only retain the keys of the dictionary

Answer (score 5):

Convert it to string, in case you need to store in a db. If you wrap it in a list, you won't be able to query it.

```
dic={'key':1}
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a'][1] = str(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is prob a bug Pandas needs to fix. But here's a workaround:

```
data.loc[0:0, 'new column'] = [d]
```

Basically, use .loc 0:0 to refer to the first row, then assign dictionary in [].