# Value assignment to a particular position in a dataframe is not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to assign a nested dict to a particular position, but it is'nt working. Here is what I wrote :

```
def history_current(df):
    df_this = df.copy()
    leid_val = {}
    leid_index = {}
    run_seq_min = min(df.run_seq.values)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.run_seq == run_seq_min:
            print({row.cp_id : { row.products : {row.currency : {row.tran_amnt}}}})
            df_this.loc[idx, 'current'] = {row.cp_id : { row.products : {row.currency : {row.tran_amnt}}}}
            print(df_this)
```

but it gives the following output for the first iteration :

```
{201: {'U': {'USD': {100}}}}
    le_id  run_seq  cp_id cp_name products  tran_amnt currency  current  \
0     101        1    201       A        U        100      USD      201.0   
1     102        1    202       B        U        200      USD      NaN   
2     103        1    202       B        V        672      INR      NaN   
3     104        2    201       A        W        892      YEN      NaN   
4     105        2    208       H        V        739      SGD      NaN   
5     101        3    203       C        X        982      INR      NaN   
6     103        3    204       D        Z        739      USD      NaN   
7     101        3    205       E        Z        537      YEN      NaN   
8     101        3    206       F        Y        263      ISD      NaN   
9     102        3    206       F        Y        638      INR      NaN   
10    104        3    205       E        X        437      SGD      NaN   
11    102        3    203       C        V        783      INR      NaN   
12    103        4    204       D        U        738      UEB      NaN   
13    103        4    204       D        Z        893      INR      NaN   
14    103        4    207       G        M        637      YEN      NaN   
15    101        4    202       B        W        783      SGD      NaN   
16    104        5    201       A        Y        927      USD      NaN   
17    104        5    203       C        Z        637      YEN      NaN   
18    103        5    207       G        U        748      USD      NaN   
19    102        5    208       H        W        126      INR      NaN   

    history  
0       NaN  
1       NaN  
2       NaN  
3       NaN  
4       NaN  
5       NaN  
6       NaN  
7       NaN  
8       NaN  
9       NaN  
10      NaN  
11      NaN  
12      NaN  
13      NaN  
14      NaN  
15      NaN  
16      NaN  
17      NaN  
18      NaN  
19      NaN
```

However, what I expect is `{201: {'U': {'USD': {100}}}}` in the first row under current and consictively for the whole dataframe using row values.

Note that, current and history were created using 'np.nan` to be populated later with nested dictionaries.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question but I see  tran_amnt is 101 int the first row, or did you intend to get le_id?

Comment: Could you please provide your exact expected output?  Also, You can probably simplify your sample data, e.g. the first five rows only and possible removing columns which are not needed.

Comment: @Alexander I want to assign a nested dictionary as in the code to the output where `201.0` is printed under `current` column and thus for every row in the dataframe using the row values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your dict expression in square brackets:

```
df_this.loc[idx, 'current'] = [{row.cp_id : { row.products : {row.currency : row.tran_amnt}}}]
```

it can help.

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710501/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-dictionary-as-an-entry-of-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python).

Comment: That was a mistake, I printed 'df' while I was working with 'df_this'. But the changes that you suggested gives the almost the same result. Read the question again, I have edited it.

Comment: Updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `iloc` instead. `loc` is supposed to work with conditions while `iloc` works with positions. Since you are feeding a position (`idx`), using `iloc` should work

Comment: When I use .iloc It gives the following error : `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'type'>
`

Comment: I tried this  - `df_this.loc[idx]['current'] = {row.cp_id : { row.products : {row.currency : {row.tran_amnt}}}}` but it doesn't work either.